# How to allow loading a page in iframe on Messenger and Facebook domains

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, facebook-chatbot

I am using iframe to display a page on facebook Messenger web following the below article :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#webview_on_web

I already whitelisted my domain but now I want to allow the loading of these pages on iframe. For that I need to set **X-Frame-Options** HTTP response header to allow my page within an iframe.

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/
```

My question is how and where to set this response header.

Comment: Depends on your system ... Could happen at the web server level, could happen from within your server-side script code, ...

Comment: Your .htaccess file is probably the easiest place.

Comment: @CBroe in case you're using `php` how would you set that in the script files?